# 'timespec':'struct' type redefinition when using pthread library

Tags: c

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLCON.png)There is an output error

> 'timespec':'struct' type redefinition
>   i used visual studio 2017 , c compiler
>   i use windows 7

and I don't understand what's the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 4

void *hello(void *arg) { /* thread main */
  printf("Hello Thread\n");
  return 0;
}

int main(void) {
  int i;
  pthread_t tid[NUM_THREADS];

  for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) { /* create/fork threads */
    pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, hello, NULL);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) { /* wait/join threads */
    pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add: Which OS? Which compiler? How is the compiler  called? Last not least: What is the complete and exact error message you get? Are there other messages as well?

Comment: A consistent indentation style would really help make your code more readable, btw.

Comment: There is no _struct_ definition in your code, are you sure the program you give produce the error when you compile it ? As is it already request copy/paste the message produced by the compiler and give details about your configuration. You need to give the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) else it is impossible for us to help you, we do not have a magic crystal ball

Comment: Do you get a file and/or line number on the error?  If so, include that.

Comment: OT: the proper way to return from a thread function is: `pthread_exit( NULL )`  So using `return 0` is discouraged

Comment: I ran your code using `gcc` on linux.   The only message was: "untitled2.c:6:19: warning: unused parameter ‘arg’ [-Wunused-parameter]"  The line immediately following: `void *hello(void *arg) { ` should be: `(void)arg;`

Comment: OT: when calling C library functions, always check the returned value to assure there was no error.  Suggest initializing the array `tid[]` to all 0s then in the `pthread_join()` loop to not call that function is the value in the current entry in `tid[]` is 0

Comment: i didn't get the error in which line